# PowerPoint with embedded video on OS X and Windows

Tags: macos, windows-xp, windows-vista, video, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation with an embedded video (I tried both `.mp4` and `.avi`). It works perfectly on Mac OS X, but on Windows XP and Vista, the video doesn't start.

I need it to work also on Windows OS (at least XP and Vista), what could be the problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Pekka: I succeed in viewing the video on QuickTime (the .mp4 video, about 8MB), but in the presentation it doesn't start. I've exported the video from camtasia trial version for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of Windows PowerPoint that will embed video is 2010.  Embedded videos will play in it and also in PowerPoint 2007 IF Service Pack 2 is applied (and presumably later SPs, if and when they become available).

I think embedded vids will play in the latest version of the free Viewer but not in earlier versions.

If you use QuickTime movies, QuickTime must also be installed on the Windows PC in order to play the video.  You can make them more widely compatible by opening the presentation in 2010 on a PC with QT installed and using the optimize feature on the vids (which converts them into a format that doesn't require QT on the playback PC).

Comment: I've converted the .mp4 video to .wmp and now it starts. I use MS Office 2003. When I click "insert video from file" is it embedded? I don't know if I've made a mistake in the question. If the video is embedded, how can it work in Office 2003?

Comment: PowerPoint 2003 does not embed videos, it links to them.  The best way to ensure that the links don't break is to first put the video files in the same folder as the PowerPoint presentation and THEN insert them.  Then if you make sure that both the PPT and the vids stay in the same folder (any folder) together on other PCs, the links will work.  That's half the problem.  The other half is making sure that the playback machine has the necessary codecs to play the video.